# compute a vector which is perpendicular to another given vector (all are in 3D)

Tags: c++, math, vector, computational-geometry

I have a vector `v1` (suppose `v1= a1,b2,c1`) and this `v1` passes through the point `x1,y1,z1`. Now I need a second vector, `v2` which is perpendicular to the `v1`. Suppose that `v2` is passing through the second point `x2,y2,z2`.

However, my final goal is to find the intersection point of above two lines. So, could you help me to find the vector which is perpendicular to another given vector?  PLZ Anyone helps me.

Comment: You should post math questions on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: sorry, but i found similar questions are also posted in this forum

Comment: What do you mean by a vector "passing through a point"?

Comment: I think he meant `(a1, b1, c1) = α (x1, y1, z1)` for some scalar `α`, not that it matters…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing, do you want to find the point of intersection or do you want a perpendicular vector?

There's an infinite amount of vectors that are perpendicular to your given vector. If you want just any of those, turn your `v1` vector by 90 degrees: `v2 = (-y1, x1, z1)`.

As for the line crossing, take into account that (as said before) 2 lines in 3D space will almost never cross each other. Solution: http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0106/algorithm_0106.htm.

Google is your friend.

Comment: i want to get the intersection point.

Comment: Well... it's in my answer, see the link I gave, everything you need (and more) is explained there.

Comment: assuming v1 = (x1, y1, z1), then v2 = (-y1, x1, z1) is not necessarily perpendicular to v1. suppose v1=(0, 0, 1), then v2=v1 and the two are not perpendicular.

Comment: `if x1 == 0 then v2 = (1,0,0);
elif y1 == 0 then v2 = (0,1,0);
elif z1 == 0 then v2 = (0,0,1);
else v2 = (-y1, x1, 0);`

Comment: `(-y1, x1, z1)` is not perpendicular to `(x1, y1, z1)` in general : `(-y1, x1, z1) * (x1, y1, z1) = -x1*y1 + x1*y1 + z1*z1 = z1^2`

Answer (score 0):

In 3D, there are an infinite number of perpendicular vectors to any given vector. For any vector direction, *i.e.*, no specific direction, you can take the cross-product of the your vector and any other vector.

Comment: thanks for the comments. but, that perpendicular vector should passes through a specific point.so, does my vector is still be the one iwhich is given by cross prodcut?

Comment: There are infinite number of vectors passing through the specific point that are orthogonal to specific vector. Imagine vector v = (0, 0, 1). Any vector that lies in XY plane will be orthogonal to v, and there could be infinite vectors that pass through the point (1, 2, 0) for example.

Comment: @ paul, i got. but, fianlly both vectors should be intersect.

Comment: The cross product approach will only work if you can generate another vector which isn't parallel to the given vector.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinite number of vectors that are orthogonal to the given vector. Also, two arbitrary lines may not intersect in 3D.

Comment: if i need to find that vector in a way, that this passes through a given point, then how can i get the perpendicular vector?

Comment: @g_niro Find any perpendicular vector. Now shift it so it goes through your given point. Note again that there's an infinite number of possibilities.

Comment: true, i got you now. but finally these two vectors (or straight lines) should be intersect. then, is still your comment valid?